# How to pass a callback action method in JSF2?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, callback, parameter-passing

I'm using Primefaces `p:dialog` with two beans in action: one is the backing bean of the original page (A) and the other bean is the one behind `p:dialog` (B). Both are view-scoped beans.

Is this possible to pass a callback method to B as a parameter so that B can call this method and fire some actions on A with proper parameters? Something like this:

```
<p:dialog ...>
    <ui:include>
         <ui:param name="callback" value="[a possible callback method]" />
    </ui:include>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

`a.xhtml`:

```
....

<p:dialog ...>
    <ui:include src="b.xhtml">
         <ui:param name="targetObject" value="#{bean.value}" />
    </ui:include>
</p:dialog>
```

Then in `b.xhtml`

```
<p:commandLink>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{targetObject}" value="#{objectInDialog}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

This causes a click on the commandLink in dialog a call to `bean.setValue(objectInDialog)`